# Printing numbers framed to digits in C# terminal

Tags: c#, printing, terminal

I've got this problem as an assignement at the University. The problem is how to make numbers printed like this, where digits are lined with each other, automatically like seen on the picture below.

[image: sample output]

That's my code right now.

```
        public class Tabliczka
    {
        private int n;
        public Tabliczka(int n)
        {
            this.n = n;
        }

        public void wyswietl()
        {
            for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
                {
                    if (i * j <= 9) Console.Write("   {0}", i * j);
                    if (i * j > 9 && i * j <= 99) Console.Write("  {0}", i * j);
                    if (i * j > 99) Console.Write(" {0}", i * j);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

It's not a good solution because it'll format it correctly only to 999. Thanks in advance for any tips :).

Answer (score 0):

We just need to properly format the numbers:

```
public void wyswietl()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0, 10}", i * j));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```